# Es6.promise.js file: Unable to get property raise of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, wijmo5

I have a react app that triggers this exception right when I attempt to `setState`. I find the exception in a file called `es6.promise.js`. Does anyone know what package this file is from and what this error is about?

I don't know if this has anything to do with it but I'm using `wijmo's collectionView` to set my state to it.

```
this.setState({rowData: collectionView});
```

Comment: Please provide the exception you get

Comment: That's the exception Unable to get property raise ...

Comment: as the word `raise` doesn't appear in the single line of "code" you've posted, I'm taking a guess that is not the line that is causing the error - surely the error comes complete with the location (file and line number) of the offending code, and most likely a stack trace to help debug your error